# How can I test whether or not a default font feature has been set?

Tags: fontspec, package-writing

When I use the `fontawesome` package (in conjunction with `fontspec`+`xelatex`), I I specify the file extension using the key `Extension` from `fontspec`'s `\defaultfontfeatures`.

> `\defaultfontfeatures{Extension=.otf}`

How can I get the value of `Extension` later?

Comment: Not on my (current) system. fontawesome loads fontspec without options. There is no clash.

Comment: You are saying that you get an "option clash" error. You get such errors from the package loading not from the font choices. E.g. `\usepackage{fontspec}\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}` gives this error. If you get it then your fontawesome version (or some other package) is loading fontspec with an option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yep. I misunderstood the error. This question is not relevant to my problem anymore. I am deciding whether or not to close it. (somewhere I had `\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}`). Maybe it would still be interesting to access the value of `Extension`. I changed the wording accordingly.